# Inline-block new line

Tags: css

I have 4 elements in one row, each as inline-block. Im doing responsive website, so I want to move 2 elements to new line at some resolution. Because im using media-queries I need to do this in CSS. Does anyone know how solve this problem?

My code:
https://jsfiddle.net/451ouudn/

```
<div id="servicesPanel">
    <div id="servicesContent" data-animate="fadeIn">
        <h2>OFERTA</h2>
        <span>Gwarantujemy najwyższą jakość w rozsądnych cenach! </span>
        <div id="services">
            <div class="item" id="face">KOSMETYKA TWARZY</div>
            <div class="item" id="handsAndFeet">KOSMETYKA DŁONI I STÓP</div>
            <div class="item" id="solarium">SOLARIUM</div>
            <div class="item" id="hairdressing">FRYZJERSTWO</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are your media queries?

Comment: In my full project. First, I want to solve it in the usual version

Comment: You say you are using (and want to use) media queries but you haven't supplied them. Media queries WOULD be the usual version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this you have to increase the width of item div in media query so that they will come in 2 lines.
for example:

```
@media(max-width:1024px){
 .item{ width:49%;} 
}
```

here we give 49% width to each div.